# docker exec sees changes in local files

Tags: django, docker

I am playing with django project in docker and reality of the situation contradicts my limited understanding:
after I change file tests.py and run
`docker exec {my_container} python manage.py test`
it knows these local changes that I've made (for example I can write new test and it will run).
But I thought that docker containers are isolated and I need to recreate or at least copy updated file to one in order to update state of files.

I read [docker exec doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) but found no info about its ability to update files in container.
So, what do I need to know in order to understand what is happening?

---

### EDIT

content of Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD . /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  ankete_db:
    image: postgres
    ports: 
      - "54320:5432"
    container_name: ankete_db
  ankete:
    build: .
    container_name: ankete
    command: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 ankete.wsgi
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - ankete_db
```

Comment: What is the command used to start the container?

Comment: docker-compose up -d --force-recreate

Comment: Do you have any volumes in the Dockerfile?

Comment: in dockerfile no, but I have one in docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference) in your docker-compose.yml does this. Once you remove `volumes` your changes shuldn't be reflected in a container.

Answer (score 2):

The exec command does not update files between host and container. What is causing the files to be synced between container and host is the volume declared inside the compose file.

The volume declaration mounts the directory `.` onto `/code` inside the container, such that any changes done to any file inside the host current directory are reflected in the `/code` directory inside the container and vice versa.

Comment: nice to know, but can you add link and/or quote where that is clearly stated?

Comment: @GrailFinder This is the idea behind a bind mount in Docker. You can read more about it under https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#start-a-container-with-a-bind-mount

Comment: yeah, I meant adding that to your answer